# Shaving off SQL data before and after character

Tags: sql, replace, amazon-redshift

I am trying to extract SQL data before and after a _ character, however there are multiple _ within each string.

For example, in the string `02_HVDO_HistoryOfScience_100__517` I just want the result to be `HistoryOfScience`or whatever is the longest string of words.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Edit your question and tag the database you are using.  And explain how you arrive at "HistoryOfScience" instead of, say "HVDO" or "100".

Comment: You can do this using a python UDF in Redshift. need some help with that?

Comment: Sam, please take a look at my solution below and "accept it" if it works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work

```
create or replace function f_longest_substring (s varchar(max))
  returns varchar(max)
stable
as $$
def f_longest_substring(input_string):
    parts = input_string.split("_")
    largest_string=""
    for part in parts:
        if len(part)>len(largest_string):
            largest_string=part
    return largest_string
return f_longest_substring(s)

$$ language plpythonu;

select f_longest_substring ('02_HVDO_HistoryOfScience_100__517');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming MS-SQL Server, you can create the split function from [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/querying-microsoft-sql-server/2013/09/19/how-to-split-a-string-by-delimited-char-in-sql-server/)

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnSplitString] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(splitdata NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (splitdata)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
```

and use to get your result:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM dbo.fnSplitString('02_HVDO_HistoryOfScience_100__517','_')
ORDER BY LEN(splitdata) DESC
```

Comment: Oops. Didn't see that tag!